# Tengo problemas en una query MySQL para mostrar varias fechas en una fila

Tags: mysql

Chicos, aca dando vueltas nuevamente con una consulta SQL, resulta que tengo 2 tablas: en la tabla "cursos" guardo los datos relacionados con un curso, aca les dejo la foto,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la tabla "jornadas_curso" guardo las fechas de cada curso, ya que cada curso puede tener mas de 1 fecha, esta es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la pagina principal muestro por array cada curso, con su fecha y jornada, sin embargo, si un curso tiene mas de 1 fecha, solo me muestra 1 fecha...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta SQL que ocupo para consultar por los cursos es este:

```html
SELECT 
cursos.nombre_curso, cursos.id_curso, 
DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso, '%d/%m/%y' ) AS Fechas_Cursos, 
jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
cursos.id_relator, 
cursos.descripcion, 
cursos.vacantes, 
cursos.ubicacion
FROM cursos
INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
AND disponible = 'si'
AND vacantes >0
AND fechas_curso > NOW( ) 
GROUP BY nombre_curso
ORDER BY fechas_curso DESC
```

Lo coloque como group by nombre_curso, ya que si un curso tenia mas de 1 fecha, aparecia mas de 1 fila con el nombre de curso repetido pero diferentes fechas...

El resultado actualmente de mi query en mysql es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que, por cada fila, me muestre el nombre del curso, sus datos y todas sus fechas disponibles, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*(ACTUALIZACIÓN) = También probé colocando GROUP_CONCAT para el campo Fechas_Cursos así:

```html
SELECT cursos.nombre_curso, 
cursos.id_curso, 
GROUP_CONCAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso + ' -- ' ) AS Fechas_Curso, 
jornadas_curso.horario_curso, 
jornadas_curso.tipo_jornada, 
cursos.id_relator, 
cursos.descripcion, 
cursos.vacantes, 
cursos.ubicacion
FROM cursos
INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
AND disponible = 'si'
AND vacantes >0
AND fechas_curso > NOW( ) 
GROUP BY nombre_curso
ORDER BY fechas_curso ASC
```

Y me dio este resultado en el phpmyadmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que me falta en la query SQL?, muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda...

Comment: La query correcta seria sin el `GROUP BY`.  La forma en la que quieres que se desplieguen los resultados depende de ti.

Comment: Podrias poner lo que te retorna el query vs lo que esperas que te retorne para darnos una mejor idea.

Comment: Ricardo, acabo de actualizar el post, saludos

Comment: probaste utilizando el `GROUP_CONCAT` de `mysql` para el campo `Fechas Cursos`?

Comment: Hola Ricardo, acabo de editar el post explicando que use el group_concat en el campo de Fechas_Cursos y lo puse con una foto del resultado que me da, para ver si me puedes dar una mano con ese tema please... Mil gracias!!